# Consecutive frames can be discarded when training an SSD/YOLO?

Tags: deep-learning, training, datasets, object-recognition

Let's say I have a number of videos, and I want to train an SSD/YOLO (or FRCNN) to detect objects. In the case of a large amount of videos,  there will be a lot of frames extracted and transferred to images. Can you take, for example, only the fifth frame everytime and thus lower the amount of memory required? If the frames contain a similar info, we can skip some and not impact the results? This is mainly to train faster..

Comment: Theoretically possible, but you have to modify the sorce code at video capture part. I did integrate YOLO with my C++ project and I always skip 5~10 frames per second. But I didn't modify the YOLO source code, because I capture the video frame using OpenCV in my C++ project, not directly from Yolo.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right. I used OpenCV and saved the tenth frame,  not directly from YOLO as you said. Thanks@!